# Limiting Form Submissions by Time

Tags: language-agnostic

This is not language specific.  What are the best methods to limit how many times a person may submit a web form, not knowing any info about that person.  Example: Voting for the all star game online, only allowed 1 per 24 hour cycle.  Something where you don't have to "log in".  My thoughts were:

- Use Captcha to keep bots at bay
- Drop a cookie that expires in 24 hours
- Check IP address if no cookie present (How many people are going to get banned because of NAT using this technique)
- Anything I'm missing?

Comment: what about people using public wifi that have the same IP?

Comment: yeah, that's why I'm thinking IP might be a bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good technique is to use Flash cookie. Many people clears cookies or uses different browsers. Flash cookies are cross-browser: they have same value across all browsers in your system, and people often doesn't know they exist.

How it works you can check here:

http://www.nuff-respec.com/technology/cross-browser-cookies-with-flash

Cookie and IP are of course also worth checking, but cookies don't block cheating, and IP blocks NAT users.

Comment: Wouldn't stop me unless you did the form/action in Flash -- I use Flashblock and don't allow flash unless the rest of the page gives me a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of this, definitely going to check it out

Answer (score 0):

There is another technique which identifies you upon browser and installed plugins. See [Panopticlick](http://panopticlick.eff.org/).

IMHO this is quite a exotic option.